# How to ignore folder during subversion merge

Tags: svn, repository, merge

I have a whole bunch of changes that I need to be merged in to my branch but I want to ignore a specific folder during the merge. Is it possible to do this using Subversion? If so then how can I do it?

EDIT:
The folder that I want to ignore is in the repository but I don't changes to be made to this folder during the merge

Comment: What is the role of the folder you want to ignore?  Is it an existing folder in the SubVersion repository that you don't want to be updated into your local copy, or is it a local copy you have that you don't want to be added into SubVersion?

Comment: The folder that I want to ignore is in the repository but I don't changes to be made to this folder during the merge

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do the merge as normal, then do a recursive revert (`svn revert -R somefolder`) on the folder where you don't want any changes before committing.

Keep in mind that this will introduce inaccuracies in the mergeinfo though. Subversion will think certain changes were merged to "somefolder" while in reality they were not. That will cause some interesting problems if you do want to merge those changes later on.

**edit**: note that doing a revert of somefolder will implicitly remove any pending conflicts in that folder. There's no "suffering" induced by these conflicts.

Comment: I also thought of doing this but the whole reason I wanted to avoid the merge skipping the folder is because content was merged into this folder before and because i'm doing the merge into the other folders over the same revision range I will be getting a whole lot of file and tree conflicts. Guess I will have to suffer it out and do the revert afterwards.