# Skip a file in SVN merge between branches

Tags: svn

Is it possible to skip a file during the merge between SVN branches?
I tried following svn:ignore but did not help as it supports to directories and not files.

Comment: You are merging branch A into branch B. Branch A containts file F which has modifications. So you don't want branch B to have the the modifications of file F from branch A?

Comment: @Yeti: that's right. I have a file F in both the branches and I don't want to see merge conflicts due to file F. Is there a way to skip file F when merging?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/2386825/4248273 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/2381554/4248273 ?

Comment: Checked it already. But that isn't any straightforward like a single command